# Multi-Line Powershell .CMD file

Tags: powershell, cmd, multiline

I'm attempting to create a CMD file which loads PowerShell using the standard PowerShell command on launch. The issue is it does not execute any further code once it is launched PowerShell within CMD, it basically halts.

What needs to be done in order for the rest of the code to be executed after it has loaded PS?

Sorry, I'm brand new to coding and this site!

```
powershell
$domain = "domain"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "$domain\username" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please post your code if possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I have added the code above, sorry about that. In terms of this specific solution, purely hours of searching with no come up. I have been working on this pretty much all day, attempting multiple ways to connect a new PC to the domain. I know this isn't the safest solution but we are just testing this In VM's for the time being till we iron out the kinks.

Comment: Not sure you CAN do it in one script. Powershell may well kill the initial batch. Normally you don't do powershell .cmd, you do .ps1. ps1 is the extension for powershell. Why you insist on starting with the outdated old interpreter?

Comment: Hi Tom, We're basically attempting semi-automatic PC setup using autounattend files in which we are attempting to connect the PC to the domain using a script. However it seems the only way this can be done is using the SetupComplete.cmd file which Windows searches for on first time setup before logging in. As windows is looking for a specific file name and extension we assumed this would not be possible with a ps1 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the PowerShell script into a .ps1 file as James C. suggetsted is probably the easiest way. Alternatively, it can be put into a single command. Of course, this will be expected to conform to the maximum command line length limit.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$domain = 'domain';" ^
    "$password = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force;" ^
    "$username = "$domain\username^";" ^
    "$credential = New-Object;" ^
    "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password);" ^
    "Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential;" ^
    "Restart-Computer -Force"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The commands in your bat/cmd file won't be entered into the powershell console for you. `CMD` will launch `powershell` then wait for it to exit before running the next command, or as you describe it 'halts'.

With your script just running `powershell` runs the powershell console (with an interactive prompt that waits for *user* input). It will do nothing as you are not specifying a command or file for it to run.

To make it run your command, save the commands as a `.ps1` file, then get powershell to run that file:

```
powershell -File C:\folder\script.ps1
```

---

EDIT:

You are however trying to re-invent the wheel as [unattended domain join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-unattendedjoin-identification-joindomain) is already part of the unattended answer file (see [Windows System Image Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-system-image-manager-technical-reference)) and has been available since Windows 7.

Comment: I have managed to get the script to work as per lit's answer. I did attempt to use the built-in domain join commands but was unable to get it to work after hours of testing. However, thank you for your assistance!